# Django Models Group By

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by, django-orm

I have this simple SQL query -

```
SELECT pid, COUNT(*) AS docs FROM xml_table WHERE suid='2' GROUP BY pid;
```

How do I get this using Django ORM (i.e. django models). Basically I am not getting how to do `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`XML_table.objects.filter(suid='2').values('pid').annotate(docs=Count('pid')).order_by()`

[Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 1):

This works very nicely.

```
from collections import defaultdict
count = defaultdict( int )
for doc in XML_Table.objects.filter(suid='2'):
    count[doc.pid] += 1
```

It's not SQL.  Often it's faster than SQL because it doesn't impose a sort on a large table or join result.

Comment: I'd quibble with "often". Anybody about to use this should test first. I came here because I needs counts for over a million rows. Your queryset would have to return all million. Additionally, you're returning the entire row and instantiating it -- a .values() should be a lot quicker if you go this route.