# How to execute a GROUP BY ... COUNT or SUM in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, group-by, django-orm

**Prologue:**

This is a question arising often in SO:

- [Django Models Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947475/django-models-group-by)
- [Django equivalent for count and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327807/django-equivalent-for-count-and-group-by)
- [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)
- [How to use the ORM for the equivalent of a SQL count, group and join query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175134/how-to-use-the-orm-for-the-equivalent-of-a-sql-count-group-and-join-query/45563598#45563598)

I have composed an example on SO Documentation but since the Documentation will get shut down on August 8, 2017, I will follow the suggestion of [this widely upvoted and discussed meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/354302#354302) and transform my example to a self-answered post.

Of course, I would be more than happy to see any different approach as well!!

---

**Question:**

Assume the model:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField()
    author = models.CharField()
    price = models.FloatField()
```

How can I perform the following queries on that model utilizing Django ORM:

- `GROUP BY ... COUNT`:

  ```
  SELECT author, COUNT(author) AS count
  FROM myapp_books GROUP BY author
  ```
- `GROUP BY ... SUM`:

  ```
  SELECT author,  SUM (price) AS total_price
  FROM myapp_books GROUP BY author
  ```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

We can perform a `GROUP BY ... COUNT` or a `GROUP BY ... SUM` SQL equivalent queries on Django ORM, with the use of [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset), [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), the `django.db.models`'s `Count` and `Sum` methods respectfully and optionally the [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) method:

- **GROUP BY ... COUNT:**

  ```
   from django.db.models import Count

   result = Books.objects.values('author')
                         .order_by('author')
                         .annotate(count=Count('author'))
  ```

  Now result contains a **dictionary** with two keys: `author` and `count`:

  ```
     author    | count
   ------------|-------
    OneAuthor  |   5
   OtherAuthor |   2
      ...      |  ...
  ```
- **GROUP BY ... SUM:**

  ```
   from django.db.models import Sum

    result = Books.objects.values('author')
                          .order_by('author')
                          .annotate(total_price=Sum('price'))
  ```

  Now result contains a **dictionary** with two columns: `author` and `total_price`:

  ```
     author    | total_price
   ------------|-------------
    OneAuthor  |    100.35
   OtherAuthor |     50.00
       ...     |      ...
  ```

**UPDATE 13/04/2021**

As @dgw points out in the comments, in the case that the model uses a meta option to order rows (ex. [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering)), the [`order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) clause **is paramount** for the success of the aggregation!

Comment: You should also add joined tables with group by and "having" filters.  For me it's counterintuitive because in SQL, you usually start with the parent and in django you start with the child.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale If I understand correctly what you mean, you can use `filter` before extracting the `values`.

Comment: You mean filter again after annotate, and the orm is smart enough to know it needs to do having?

Comment: Here's what worked for me: statement_line.objects.filter(pay_date__lt='2019-10-31').select_related('ae').values('ae__opp_own').annotate(tots=Sum('amt')).filter(tots__gt=0)  The critical key was the select related and the double underline for parent field name.  The second filter does turn to "having".  str([obj].query) confirms this. Another handy thing.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale This Q&A style is more general and what you have composed here doesn't really relate to the question or the answer. Are you sure this was going as a comment to this post?

Comment: Your fourth bullet point above included "join" queries, but your examples only had one model and thus table.  Joins usually uses two or more so I added the select related and double underline items in there.

Comment: Maybe one should emphasize the `order_by(...)` part. If the model uses different columns for ordering, omitting the `order_by()` clause will cause the aggregation to fail.

Comment: @dgw Good catch, I have updated the post accordingly!

Comment: Note in some cases it may be necessary to use `Sum(..., distinct=True)`.

Comment: @djvg only if you want to sum distinct prices out of your set. (ex p1=2, p2=3, p3=2, p4=3, p5=4 will have a distinct sum of 9)

Answer (score 0):

in group by SUM() you can get almost two dict objects like

```
inv_data_tot_paid =Invoice.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('amount', filter=Q(status = True,month = m,created_at__year=y)),paid=Sum('amount', filter=Q(status = True,month = m,created_at__year=y,paid=1)))
print(inv_data_tot_paid)
##output -{'total': 103456, 'paid': None}
```

do not try out more than two query filter otherwise, you will get error like