# Convert from sql to Django ORM

Tags: sql, django-orm

Help me, please! How to convert this `SELECT hotel_id FROM hotelrooms GROUP BY hotel_id HAVING COUNT(room_id) < 20` to Django ORM?

Model:

```
class hotelrooms(models.Model):
  room_id = models.IntegerField()
  hotel_id = models.IntegerField()
  price = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Can you please show the related models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem there is only one model, I updated the question

Comment: You can have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm/45547675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query with:

```
HotelRoom.objects.values('hotel_id').annotate(
    nhotel=Count('room_id')
).filter(nhotel__lt=20).order_by('hotel_id')
```

That being said, it looks like these should be [**`ForeignKey`**s [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). `ForeignKey`s refer to another model, and thus can enforce referential integrity for example.