# Summation of number in django

Tags: python, django

I have two models like this:

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Items(models.Model):
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_amount = models.FloatField()
```

now I want to get sum of item_amount according to item_type. How I can do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a GROUP BY ... COUNT or SUM in Django ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

result = Items.objects.values('item_type')
                           .order_by('item_type')
                           .annotate(total_amount=Sum('item_amount'))
```