# Django sum objects filtering another model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have this 3 models:

```js
class Provider(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField("Provider",max_length=200)
        def __str__(self):

            return  self.name

class Contract(models.Model):
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Active?")
        provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Provider")
        total_to_spent = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Total to spend")

        def __str__(self,):
            return str(self.id) + '- ' + str(self.provider)
            
            
class Invoice(models.Model):
        contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Contract",related_name='ContractObject',)
        value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Value")
        
        def __str__(self,):
            return  str(self.contract)
```

**total_to_spent** in *Contract.model* is the amount of money i can spent in that contract

**value** in *Invoice.model* is the money related to that invoice that is then associated with the contract

**My view**

```js
def ServicoView(request):
    contracts = Contract.objects.all()
    contract_active = Contract.objects.filter(active=True)
    contratos_finish = Contract.objects.filter(active=False)

    //i was trying something like this 
    for i in contracts:
        invoices= Invoice.objects.filter(contract=contract['id']).values().aggregate(total=Sum('value '))

    context = {
        'contract_active': contract_active,
        'contratos_finish':contratos_finish,
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard_servico.html', context)
```

In my view i want to do the *SUM* of  all invoices (value) related to one Contract for later compare to the *total_to_spent* to see if it passes the value or not

Answer (score 0):

> In my view i want to do the SUM of all invoices (value) related to one Contract for later compare to the total_to_spent to see if it passes the value or not

You could do use the below query to get the sum of **value** of all the invoices belonging to a particular contract with id as **contract_id**

```
Invoice.objects.filter(contract_id=contract_id).values('value').annotate(total=Sum(value))
```

A similar question is answered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm) where you can find more detailed information

Comment: Still it doesn't work, having a error *name 'contrato_id' is not defined*

Comment: It was just an example query. You of course need to set contract_id=<ID of the contract on which you want to calculate this before running the above query>